# QLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'telemark_mgn'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: magento

Trace:

> #0 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(54611):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
>    #1 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(55091):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
>    #2 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(53298):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
>    #3 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(54354):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
>    #4 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(55199):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
>    #5 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(29625):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
>    #6 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(29566):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql',
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
>    #7 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(12036):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
>    #8 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(12066):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
>    #9 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(12051):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
>    #10 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache.php(53):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
>    #11 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Cache.php(478):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
>    #12 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Cache.php(520):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
>    #13 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(21198):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
>    #14 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(22811):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
>    #15 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(22691):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
>    #16 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(20428):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
>    #17 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/includes/src/__default.php(20358):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
>    #18 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>    #19 /home/telemark/public_html/magento/index.php(71): Mage::run('', 'store')
>    #20 {main}

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: How can i fix this problem?

Comment: If you expect somebody to answer your question please provide at least the code that produces it. Here are some tips how good questions should look like: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve